# get the closest point of a line to a other point in $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: geometry

Note: I understand this question has been asked several times, but so far I haven't found any general formula, so I'm looking for that.

---

I want to get the closest point of a line to a other point in $\Bbb R^2$ . The data I have is:

- two points through which the line passes
- a point

Below is an example image

[image]

Among my attempts are:

I tried equating the parametric equations of the line and the perpendicular that passes through the point, but I was left with two equations with 3 unknowns. Plugging in the λ of the perpendicular resulted in trivial (b = b).

I also tried to see it under the concept of two right triangles, one "stuck" to the other, which I could think of thanks to the distance equation. But it is difficult for me to work with a "diagonal" line.

Comment: The formula you're looking for is here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_two_points

Comment: Are you allowed to use calculus?

Comment: @JimFerry Unfortunately, I don't have the distance nor do I know how to solve modules well. what's more, solving that equation could have more than one solution.

Comment: @SineoftheTime I don't know what you mean by "calculus". I understand that everything in mathematics is done with calculations.

Comment: So you don't know about derivatives?

Comment: @SineoftheTime I know derivatives, even though I'm rusty. But I can understand them.

Comment: Make a line perpendicular to the given line and put it through your point, then find distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is called: project the point $A$ onto the line $\ell$.
Since you have two points $P_1$ and $P_2$, then you can calculate the direction vector of the line as $d = P_2 - P_1 $, then line $\ell$ is given by $ p(t) = P_1 + t d $, where $t \in \mathbb{R}$ then the projection of $A$ onto this line is given by

$ A' = P_1 + M (A - P_1) $

where

$ M = \dfrac{ {d d}^T }{d^T d} $

For example, if $P_1 = (1, 2)$ and $P_2 = (4, 6) $ (then $ d = (3, 4) $), and the point we want to project onto the line is $A = (10, 2) $, then

$ M = \dfrac{1}{25} \begin{bmatrix} 9 && 12 \\ 12 && 16 \end{bmatrix} $

Therefore, the required point is

$ A' = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} + \dfrac{1}{25} \begin{bmatrix} 9 && 12 \\ 12 && 16 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 9 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $

And this evaluates to

$ A' =  (\dfrac{106}{25} , \dfrac{158}{25} )$

---

Another way to arrive at the above formula is as follows.  The point $A' = P_1 + t_1 d $ for some $t_1$ to be determined.  We know that

$ (A' - A) \perp d $

Hence,

$ (P_1 + t_1 d - A) \cdot d = 0 $

From which,

$ t_1 = \dfrac{ (A - P_1) \cdot d } { d \cdot d } = \dfrac{d^T (A - P_1)}{ d^T d } $

Hence,

$ A' = P_1 + t_1 d = P_1 + \dfrac{ {d d}^T }{d^T d} (A - P_1) $

And is exactly the same formula we have from the first method.

Comment: thank you! Sorry if I'm very ignorant, but how do I get d and t?

Comment: D is the second point in the line?

Comment: $d$ is the direction vector of the line, so if the two points on the line are $P_1 = (x_1, y_1)$ and $P_2 = (x_2, y_2) $ , then $d = (x_2 - x_1, y_2 - y_1) $

Comment: $t$ is an arbitrary real number.  It is not needed in this solution.  But it can be needed for other ways to solve the problem.

Comment: @DanteS.  Please check my updated solution.  It shows how to derive the formula mentioned in the solution, using orthogonality between $A' - A$ and $d$.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, where everything is happening in $\mathbb{R}^2,$ we can use basic 2D geometry. Since, we have 2 points say, $P$ and $Q,$ on which the line passes, form the equation of the line. Find the general equation of the line perpendicular to it. Solve for the arbitrary constant in that general equation of the perpendicular line by putting the point $A$ in it. Now you get two equations in two unknowns. Solve it. You get a point on the original line. Call it $B.$ Find $|AB|.$ Done.

We shall do this for the picture you have attached. The line (in green) given there is $y=x.$ The general equation of the line perpendicular to $y=x$ is $y=-x+c,c \in \mathbb{R}.$ Given point $A=(10,2).$ Solve for $c$ in the perpendicular line by putting $x=10, y=2.$ We get $c=12.$ Solve the linear equations $$y=x$$ $$y=-x+12,$$ simultaneously. We get $x=y=6.$ So, we have that $B=(6,6).$ Now $|AB|=\sqrt{(6-10)^2+(6-2)^2}=4\sqrt{2}.$

The same thing can be generalized to higher dimensions. Generalization for this involves Orthogonal complements of sets in a Normed Linear Spaces which much more interesting and has got a rich theory in itself.